# Setup project на русском языке

Tags: .net, c#

Как сделать, что бы все диалоговые окна в Setup Project были на русском языке (для Visual Studio 2008, Framework 2.0)?

Comment: в твоей программе? или в ВС08? думаю ставить русскую версию надо (=

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в свойствах проекта установить русский язык. Свойство localization в панели свойств.